# Radio button Work like dropDown (select Option)

Tags: javascript, html

My Javascript code working with select option but i want it work with radio button ,

first ,I write all code here

**Calculator Javascript:**

```
$(function(){

calc();

$("#calculator").on('change', calc);
$('#amount').bind('change keyup', calc).on('keypress', isNumberKey);
});
function isNumberKey(evt) {
var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 45 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
return true;
}

function calc() {

var plan = $("#calculator").val();
var amount = $('#amount').val();
var percent;

switch (plan) {
    case '1':
        switch (true) {
            case (amount<25):
                percent = 0;
                break;
            case (amount<=500):
                percent = 102.5;
                break;
            case (amount<=1000):
                percent = 103;
                break;
            case (amount>=10000):
                percent = 120;
                break;
            case (amount>=100001):
                percent = 0;
                break;
           default:
                percent = 0;
        }
        break;

    case '2':
        switch (true) {
            case (amount<25):
                percent = 0;
                break;
            case (amount<=1000):
                percent = 114;
                break;
            case (amount<=2000):
                percent = 118;
                break;
            case (amount<=5000):
                percent = 124;
                break;
            case (amount<=10000):
                percent = 140;
                break;
            case (amount<=20000):
                percent = 170;
                break;
            case (amount<=100000):
                percent = 220;
                break;
           default:
                percent = 0;
        }
        break;

}

$('#assign_per').val(percent+'%');
var total = amount*percent/100;
$('#total_return').val('$'+total.toFixed(2));

if(total <= 0){
    $('#net_price').val('0.00');
}else{
    $('#net_price').val('$'+(total-amount).toFixed(2));
}

}
```

**And HTML Code :**

```
                <select id="calculator">
                   <option value="1">Price One</option>
                   <option value="2">Price Two</option>
                </select> 

                <input id="amount" value="100" type="text" name="text">
                <input id="net_price" type="text" name="text" readonly>
                <input id="total_price" type="text" name="text" readonly>
```

This code work perfectly by **select option** but i need **radio button** .
In select i have **ID:calculator**  and **value in option**
How i convert it to radio button with label ?

Comment: Be careful, Java is different from Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the HTML code for your radio buttons:

```
<form id="calculator">
  <input type='radio' name='pricePlan' value='1' checked>Price One <br>
  <input type='radio' name='pricePlan' value='2'> Price Two <br>
</form>
```

And all you need to change on your javascript code is the way to get the value from the selected radio, passing the name of the radios and the form that they are in:

```
var plan = $('input[name=pricePlan]:checked', '#calculator').val()
```

Also, on your JS you are referencing the third input, `total_price`, by the wrong id, it should be:

```
$('#total_price').val('$'+total.toFixed(2));
```

Here is the full working code

```js
$(function () {

 calc();

 $("#calculator").on('change', calc);
 $('#amount').bind('change keyup', calc).on('keypress', isNumberKey);
});
function isNumberKey(evt) {
 var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
 if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 45 || charCode > 57))
  return false;
 return true;
}

function calc() {

 var plan = $('input[name=pricePlan]:checked', '#calculator').val()
 var amount = $('#amount').val();
 var percent;

 switch (plan) {
  case '1':
   switch (true) {
    case (amount < 25):
     percent = 0;
     break;
    case (amount <= 500):
     percent = 102.5;
     break;
    case (amount <= 1000):
     percent = 103;
     break;
    case (amount >= 10000):
     percent = 120;
     break;
    case (amount >= 100001):
     percent = 0;
     break;
    default:
     percent = 0;
   }
   break;

  case '2':
   switch (true) {
    case (amount < 25):
     percent = 0;
     break;
    case (amount <= 1000):
     percent = 114;
     break;
    case (amount <= 2000):
     percent = 118;
     break;
    case (amount <= 5000):
     percent = 124;
     break;
    case (amount <= 10000):
     percent = 140;
     break;
    case (amount <= 20000):
     percent = 170;
     break;
    case (amount <= 100000):
     percent = 220;
     break;
    default:
     percent = 0;
   }
   break;

 }

 $('#assign_per').val(percent + '%');
 var total = amount * percent / 100;
 $('#total_price').val('$' + total.toFixed(2));

 if (total <= 0) {
  $('#net_price').val('0.00');
 } else {
  $('#net_price').val('$' + (total - amount).toFixed(2));
 }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="calculator">
  <input type='radio' name='pricePlan' value='1' checked>Price One <br>
  <input type='radio' name='pricePlan' value='2'> Price Two <br>
</form>

<input id="amount" value="100" type="text" name="text">
<input id="net_price" type="text" name="text" readonly>
<input id="total_price" type="text" name="text" readonly>
```

Comment: @Sebastian What happens?

Comment: @Sebastian I think there is also another problem with your code, you use `total_return` on your code, but the id on the html code is `total_price`

Comment: I don't have  output , i changed the total_price also